# libjar referring to HDFS instead of local file system of a Hadoop node

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, executable-jar, local-files

All the jar files required by my MapReduce are present at local file system of the hadoop nodes (/home/ubuntu/libs/).

During the execution these are referred as hdfs://namenode-ip-address:namenodeport-number:/home/ubuntu/libs and not from the local file system of the node.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Can you paste the command you are using to see